# UTF-8 not showing in multi-dimensional arrays with a NUMERIC key

Tags: php, session, utf-8

I have a script that puts some cyrillic text into session variables like this: `$_SESSION['cyrillic'][$y]` where $y is an iterator, so in the end the array will look like this:

```
[cyrillic] => Array
    (
        [0] => ������
        [1] => ��������
        [2] => ������
        [3] => ������
```

However, after struggling with UTF-8 headers in both PHP, HTML and files save charsets (with and without BOM), I've found out there is nothing wrong with the charset settings (apparently), as setting any other session variable with the cyrillic text in WILL WORK.

This means:`$_SESSION['cyr']['txt'] = $cyrillic_string_here;` will work just fine, as shown here:

`[cyr] => Array
        (
            [txt] => десять
        )`

So, what I fail to understand then, is WHY can't I insert cyrillic into an array using a numeric key, but an alphabetical one? And how can I work around this when I -need- to use an iterating loop?

EDIT: It's not that. I can insert the same text into another variable and echo it, or a session variable without numeric key values and it will work fine.

EDIT: I also found this:

*The hard-to-find documentation sentence I'm about is: "The keys in the $_SESSION associative array are subject to the same limitations as regular variable names in PHP."*

But I thought I could make an array with a numeric value like this: $array[$i]? Or does it mean since the key is ASSOC that $array['text'][$i] wouldn't work?

Comment: I can't see the characters on the first block as well. Are you sure you wrote them in a text editor when the encoding was on UTF-8?

Comment: It will have absolutely _nothing_ to do with arrays or numeric keys. The problem must occur somewhere else, most likely wrong character set for db-connections, headers, etc.

Comment: The output rather implies that your data isn’t UTF-8 encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I had a `trim(strtolower($text));` wrapped around my cyrillic.

strtolower:

[These functions] only work when translation is between common characters in ISO 8859-1 and UTF-8, that means they will work well with western languages but not cyrillic or asian.

Thanks for your help.